# Windows Phone 8.1 comparing Control.Content giving wrong result

Tags: c#, windows-phone, boolean, compare

I'm experiencing a really weird problem I have the following piece of code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Board.Length - 2; i++)
{
    var a = Board[i].Content;
    var b = Board[i + 1].Content;
    var c = Board[i + 2].Content;
    if (a == b && a == c &&
        (string) a != string.Empty && a != null)
    {
        MessageDialog msd = new MessageDialog("test");
        await msd.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Where `Board` is an array of buttons and a,b,c have the same value of "1". However when comparing them in the if statement they all give false ? The other statements where I check if the string is empty or null give value of true.

Comment: What are the types of `a`, `b` and `c`? From the cast inside the if statement, I'm guessing they are `objects`, which means you are doing a reference equality comparison rather than value equality comparison

Comment: You are right .. they are objects I thought that it works like windows forms taking the Control.text will result in a string, however content doesn't seem to return string. How can I compare text's of controls than ? Is the only way doing `Content.ToString()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a reference equality comparison instead of a value equality comparison. Your code is equivelent to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Board.Length - 2; i++)
{
    object a = Board[i].Content;
    object b = Board[i + 1].Content;
    object c = Board[i + 2].Content;
    if (a == b && a == c &&
        (string) a != string.Empty && a != null)
    {
        MessageDialog msd = new MessageDialog("test");
        await msd.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

This means that `a == b` is being resolved as `<object> == <object>` rather than `<string> == <string>`, which results in a comparison equivelent to `Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)`. To get value equality, you should immediately cast `a`, `b` and `c`. Now that `a` is a string, you can also use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of manually checking both:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Board.Length - 2; i++)
{
    string a = (string)Board[i].Content;
    string b = (string)Board[i + 1].Content;
    string c = (string)Board[i + 2].Content;
    if (a == b && a == c && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
    {
        MessageDialog msd = new MessageDialog("test");
        await msd.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work before obviously because they were objects, now that they are strings you can switch the if to `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)`